# .Net core connection to mongo db not working

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-query

I am trying to connect to Mongo DB with .net Core but when calling to the api I get timeout error.
I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-a-mongodb-database-in-a-asp-net-core-web-api-application-b0451ae314f5

and you can take a look at the full code of this tutorial in this git repo: https://github.com/walpoles93/AspNetCoreMongoDb

I also tried to download this repository and add my user and password of mongo but still same error.
The error i get is:
`System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00.tvnqj.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/cluster0-shard-00-00.tvnqj.mongodb.net:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.`

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and the way I managed to solve this was by adding my IP address to the list of allowed Network connections to the Database on the MongoDB cloud dashboard!
[image: Network not added]

Answer (score 2):

I think you should follow the official Microsoft documentation on creating a .Net Core API with MongoDB.

[Create a web API with ASP.NET Core and MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Hope I helped a little.

Comment: Tried that, but i am trying to connect to the cloud mongo db not locally.

Comment: Have you tried reading MongoDB's documentation about Atlas?
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/

Comment: I can literally connect to the same cluster and database using nodejs but not using .net core..

Comment: @אוריזבידה .net can be a little difficult to set up sometimes. make sure your .net framework is updated. also i would recommend using sql database to connect with .net core since they are more compatible together

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a CRUD operation using ASP.NET Core with Mongo. Below I attach link

You can [refer here](https://github.com/Shashwat-Prakash/AgentyAnalytics/blob/master/Repository/MyResumeRepository.cs)

It will help you